# Форма авторизации HTML&PHP в модальном окне

Tags: javascript, php, html

Есть форма с авторизацией. Когда вводим логин и пароль которые не содержаться в СУБД, то страница просто обновляется. Это можно было бы сделать намного проще, но вот форма находится в модальном окне. Т.е. если делать проверку уже в php файле, тогда только при нажатии на кнопку авторизации срабатывает файл php и выводит сообщении об ошибке. Дык в чем суть, можно ли сделать проверку на существование пользователя прямо в HTML, ну или на крайняк в js? Спасибо.

Comment: На html-странице, при нажатии на кнопку авторизации - отправлять ajax-запрос на uri php-скрипта. Php-скрипт сделает проверку и вернет значение `0` - успех или значение `1` - ошибка. Результат ajax-запроса анализируется на стороне html-страницы и, в зависимости от полученного значения, выводит текст с ошибкой авторизации или редиректит на страницу успешного входа пользователя.

Comment: html не может обрабатывать информацию, хранящуюся на сервере, ибо это просто язык разметки. для вализации используйте php и js (ajax)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте ajax

1. Делаем отдельный обработчик для авторизации auth.php

```
$errors = [];
if (!authUser($login, $pass)) { // некий метод для авторизации
    $errors[] = 'Ошибка авторизации';
}

// тут мы либо рендерим форму авторизации с учетом ошибки
return render($errors);

// или возвращаем только ошибки
return json_encode($errors);
```

2. Делаем обработчик формы в js

```
$('.auth-form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // чтоб страница не обновилась
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(response){
            // если это html
            $('.form-container').html(response);
            // если это json
            $('.errors', form).html(''); // чистим ошибки
            if (response.errors) {
                for(var i=0; i<response.errors.length; i++) {
                   $('.errors', form).append('<p>'+response.errors[i]+'</p>');
                }
            } else {
                // ошибок нет, скорее всего нас авторизовали
                // можно просто перезагрузить страницу
                location.href = location.href;
            }
        }
    });
});
```